# mongodb: $and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this very simple query where I want to fetch shops based on multiple shopNumbers.

Here is my query:

```
Shops.find({ 
        shopNumber: { $in: ["1000"]} 
    }, 
    { 
        fields: { title: 1, shopNumber: 1 } 
    }
).fetch();
```

Now since this shop exists in database, so it works perfectly fine.

But when I supply some wrong shop number which does not exists in my database like this:

```
Shops.find({ 
        shopNumber: { $in: ["dfgdfhdfh"]} 
    }, 
    { 
        fields: { title: 1, shopNumber: 1 } 
    }
).fetch();
```

I get this error:

```
MongoServerError: $and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array
     at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\4.3.1\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:462:30)
     at MessageStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
     at MessageStream.emit (domain.js:475:12)
     at processIncomingData (C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\4.3.1\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
     at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\4.3.1\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
     at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
     at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
     at Socket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:731:22)
     at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
     at Socket.emit (domain.js:475:12)
     at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
     at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
     at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
   ok: 0,
   code: 2,
   codeName: 'BadValue',
   '$clusterTime': {
     clusterTime: Timestamp { low: 1, high: 1686589614, unsigned: true },
     signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: 0 }
   },
   operationTime: Timestamp { low: 1, high: 1686589614, unsigned: true }
 }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: hmm is $and/$or/$nor used

Comment: What is doen with the return value?

Comment: Do any of the _"wrong shop number"s_ begin with `$`?